# Parsing HTML Tables with BS4

Tags: python-2.7, html-parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying different methods of scraping data from this site (http://nflcombineresults.com/nflcombinedata.php?year=1999&pos=WR&college=) and can't seem to get any of them to work. I've tried playing with the indices given, but can't seem to make it work. I think I've tried too many things at this point,so if someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

I would like to pull all of the information and export it to a .csv file, but at this point I'm just trying to get the name and position to print to get started.

Here's my code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = ('http://nflcombineresults.com/nflcombinedata.php?year=1999&pos=&college=')

page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
table = soup.find('table')

for row in table.findAll('tr')[0:]:
    col = row.findAll('tr')
    name = col[1].string
    position = col[3].string
    player = (name, position)
    print "|".join(player)
```

Here's the error I'm getting: 
line 14, in  name = col[1].string
IndexError: list index out of range.

***--UPDATE--***

Ok, I've made a little progress. It now allows me to go from start to finish, but it requires knowing how many rows are in the table. How would I get it to just go through them until the end?
Updated Code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = ('http://nflcombineresults.com/nflcombinedata.php?year=1999&pos=&college=')

page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
table = soup.find('table')


for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:250]:
    col = row.findAll('td')
    name = col[1].getText()
    position = col[3].getText()
    player = (name, position)
    print "|".join(player)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out after only 8 hours or so. Learning is fun. Thanks for the help Kevin!
It now includes the code to output the scraped data to a csv file. Next up is taking that data and filtering out for certain positions....

Here's my code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = ('http://nflcombineresults.com/nflcombinedata.php?year=2000&pos=&college=')

page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
table = soup.find('table')

f = csv.writer(open("2000scrape.csv", "w"))
f.writerow(["Name", "Position", "Height", "Weight", "40-yd", "Bench", "Vertical", "Broad", "Shuttle", "3-Cone"])
# variable to check length of rows
x = (len(table.findAll('tr')) - 1)
# set to run through x
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:x]:
    col = row.findAll('td')
    name = col[1].getText()
    position = col[3].getText()
    height = col[4].getText()
    weight = col[5].getText()
    forty = col[7].getText()
    bench = col[8].getText()
    vertical = col[9].getText()
    broad = col[10].getText()
    shuttle = col[11].getText()
    threecone = col[12].getText()
    player = (name, position, height, weight, forty, bench, vertical, broad, shuttle, threecone, )
    f.writerow(player)
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't run your script due to firewall permissions, but I believe the problem is on this line:

```
col = row.findAll('tr')
```

`row` is a `tr` tag, and you're asking BeautifulSoup to find all tr tags within that tr tag. You probably meant to do:

```
col = row.findAll('td')
```

---

Furthermore, since the actual text isn't directly inside the tds but is also hidden within nested `div`s and `a`s, it may be useful to use the `getText` method instead of `.string`:

```
name = col[1].getText()
position = col[3].getText()
```

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Thank you! Ok, so I made the changes you suggested and am definitely making progress as it printed most of the results on the page. It started with Adrian Dingle though, and not the first name in the column, but printed the list complete after that including the | and the position. It then returned this error: File "nfltest.py", line 14, in <module> name = col[1].getText() IndexError: list index out of range. Again, I tried playing with the indices and couldn't seem to get rid of the error. Is it just me, or is this table formatted strangely?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to parse the table column wise:

```
def table_to_list(table):
    data = []
    all_th = table.find_all('th')
    all_heads = [th.get_text() for th in all_th]
    for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
        all_th = tr.find_all('th')
        if all_th:
            continue
        all_td = tr.find_all('td')
        data.append([td.get_text() for td in all_td])
    return list(zip(all_heads, *data))

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
bs = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
all_tables = bs.find_all('table')
table_to_list(all_tables[0])
```

Comment: In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)